# Re-order before GROUP BY mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following data in a table. I want to return them latest added first and I want to return only one example track (there can be multiple with same name) but, if the track has backing vocals (BVox), that must be returned first.

Example data:

```
Track_id      Artist      Title         BVox
9             ADELE       SKYFALL       NO
8             ADELE       SKYFALL       YES
7             AVICII      WAKE ME UP    YES
6             AVICII      WAKE ME UP    NO
5             OLLY MURS   DEAR DARLIN'  NO
```

I want to return:

```
Track_id      Artist      Title         BVox
8             ADELE       SKYFALL       YES
7             AVICII      WAKE ME UP    YES
5             OLLY MURS   DEAR DARLIN'  NO
```

So, I need to group them by **Artist** & **Title**, which is easy enough, **BUT**, the group needs to be ordered by BVox descending first.

I cannot simply search for all where **BVox='Yes'** because the Olly Murs track has no BVox yet I want it to show up as latest releases.

I am using the following but I think that they are grouped first and then ordered which is no good as it then shows the ADELE track but with **BVox='No'**

```
SELECT
  *,
  COUNT(*) How_many_tot
FROM
  tracks
GROUP BY
  artist, Title
ORDER BY
  track_id desc limit 50
```

Is this possible?

Comment: I think referring to the `BVox` column when you're grouping by the `artist` and the `title` is illogical. What meaning does it have?

Comment: @Itay The pupose of BVox being first is that they are a selection of tracks ordered by newest first, then samples are offered, but, if the track has BVox I want that as the sample

Comment: @Itay the how_many_tot shows how many variations of the track there are - there could be some with and without BVox, in different song keys etc. this information is shown in the page

Comment: Okay but I can't understand the logic of using a column you're not whom you're not grouping by (and isn't an aggregate function).

Comment: I don't really understand what that means but if you're referring to how_many_tot col, this shows a user that there are actually 4 different versions of a track, but, I show a sample of only one otherwise the page looks naff with each track repeated e.g. 4 times in its various guises e.g. diff song key, with/without BVox etc

Comment: I understand what's the count column for. I'm talking about the illogical usage of `BVOX` which is not a part of the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @Itay Pls see post below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT  * FROM  Table1
  ORDER BY
  field(BVOX,'YES') desc, track_id desc) abc
GROUP BY artist, Title
```

**[SAMPLE FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ee370/7)**

Comment: @Itay *the group needs to be **ordered by BVox descending first***

Comment: This is actually v close to be ing correct, actual solution is:
SELECT * FROM(SELECT
  *
FROM
  tracks
ORDER BY
  field(BVOX,'YES') desc, track_id desc) abc
GROUP BY artist, Title order by track_id desc limit 50

Comment: How does this gives the Count in the result? (besides the abomination of ORDER BY in a derived table)

Comment: OP doesn't need count